# using def with tkinter to make simple wikipedia app in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am beginner in python. I am trying to make a python wiki app that gives you a summary of anything that you search for.
My code is below:

```
import wikipedia


    question = input("Question: ")
    wikipedia.set_lang("en" )
    print (wikipedia.summary(question) )
```

This code works but I want to add a `tkinter` GUI to the app with an entry field and a search button. The result of the search will then be displayed in the GUI in a text box.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! To get some help in writing your tkinter GUI app, please show some effort in getting started and doing some research!

Comment: @Rloqvist,chances are,he already tried

Comment: Where is your TKinter code? You have to show some kind of effort for what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: @silverhash irregardless, not noticable in the question.

Comment: It looks like the first thing you should do is find a tkinter tutorial, and work your way through it. Then, try to do what you want. If you get stuck on a specific part of the problem, that's when you should come back and ask a question. As written, this is simply too broad. You're asking us to write a program for you.

Comment: @Rloqvist  i have done research on that before posting here

Comment: Tkinter code isn't part of my post because it simply doesn't work no matter how i try

Comment: @Bryan i am not asking anyone to write a code for me. i am asking for direction.it could be a suggestion to a material or tutorial online, or anything because writing the code for me here wont make me understand the code.Thank You

Comment: unfortunately, asking for links to tutorials or other resources is off topic for stackoverflow. A quick search on google should be all that  you need.

Comment: Someone already did and it has gone a long way to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you really did research and came out empty(which is highly unlikely),you could use something like

```
from tkinter import *
import wikipedia

def on_click():
  q = get_q.get()
  text.insert(INSERT, wikipedia.summary(q))

root = Tk()
question = Label(root, text="Question")
question.pack()
get_q = Entry(root, bd =5)
get_q.pack()
submit = Button(root,text='Submit',command=on_click)
submit.pack()
text = Text(root)
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Do try to research more and [readthedocs](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/library/tkinter.html),they are your best friend in programming

Comment: thank You Very much for your time and effort. your code is  very understandable to my level.TBH i did research. i  am  beginner who is interested in python as hobby.thanks for your help