# How to make an input function to find something in a certain row in a CSV file using Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, tkinter

Okay so I'm making a GUI to look for a specific number in a CSV file basically

```
ID: Name: Address: Email:
1023 John  123 Normal St John123@hotmail.com
```

So basically I want the person using the GUI to type in the ID and the GUI just goes through the CSV file and prints the whole row

Also I'm a novice coder so please don't judge me if I keep asking what a certain element is or what does this thing do

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking how to build the Tkinter interface or how to read the CSV file or both?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to do both

Answer (score 0):

First Off CSV stands for Comma Separated Values so naturally,we would expect your columns to be **comma-separated** not **space -separated**,I tried to adapt the code with your data but in the future,do **separate** your `.csv` data with **commas**

You could simply use  `readlines` to read the contents of a `.csv` file.The logic you are looking for will be something like:

```
idx = 2710
with open('my.csv','r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
for d in data:
    if d.find(str(idx)) != -1:
        print(d)
        break
```

i have already answered a similar question on the `tkinter` gui [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097663/using-def-with-tkinter-to-make-simple-wikipedia-app-in-python/47098208?noredirect=1#comment81146470_47098208),which applies to the same case as yours,all you have to do is paste the above logic into the `on_click` function and replace `print(d)` with `text.insert(INSERT, d)`

I would recommend reading about [tkinter](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/library/tkinter.html),also just a side dish [pandas](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pandas/) has some nice functions for working with `.csv` files,worth reading about